# oracle expression of wrong type while checking variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing a checking on the column length and precision , if the precision is higher than on the database then I should execute the alter system.

the error it seems is here `(COL_COUNT <> 0 AND TO_NUMBER(OLD_LENGTH) < 6,2 )`

edit

```
DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
OLD_LENGTH number(6);
 old_prec number(6);
BEGIN
COL_COUNT:= 0;
SELECT DATA_LENGTH, DATA_PRECISION INTO OLD_LENGTH , old_prec  FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME='EX_EMPLOYEE' AND COLUMN_NAME='ID';
SELECT COUNT (1) INTO COL_COUNT FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='EX_EMPLOYEE'AND COLUMN_NAME='ID';
IF (COL_COUNT <> 0 AND to_number(OLD_LENGTH) < 6.2 ) THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TABLE EX_EMPLOYEE MODIFY ID NUMERIC(6,2)');
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Try use 6.2(dot instead of comma)

Comment: The `select count()` is useless at that position in the code. If the column doesn't exist the first `select` will already throw an `ORA-01403: no data found` and the PL/SQL block will terminate

Comment: The new code is invalid PL/SQL and makes everything even more confusing

Comment: as plsql its working and compiling and i am just facing problem with the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you should compare the values for `data_length` and `data_precision`. Compare them as proper numbers, don't convert that to a string:

```
DECLARE 
  old_length NUMBER;
  old_prec   NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT data_length, coalesce(data_precision,0)
     INTO old_length, old_prec 
  FROM user_tab_cols 
  WHERE table_name='EX_EMPLOYEE' 
    AND column_name='ID';

  IF (old_length <> 6 and old_prec <> 2) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TABLE EX_EMPLOYEE MODIFY ID NUMERIC(6,2)');
  END IF;

END;
/
```

Note that the `SELECT COUNT(*)` **after** the first select is useless. If there is no such column the first `SELECT data_length, data_precision INTO` will already throw a `ORA-01403: no data found` exception and the code will never reach the check if the column exists.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using 2 variables like `INTO old_length, old_prec` if the column_name was varchar2 then `IF (old_length <> 6 and old_prec <> 2)` would be a problem to me because i dont have prec ..did you understand why I was adding it in obne variable ?

Comment: @Moudiz: then use `coalesce()` - but in that case you should probably check the actual `data_type` as well.

Comment: I added edit in my question so you can understand what I am doing , I am trying to do checking for both varchar and number , if its numeric I added the precision and length

Comment: @Moudiz: you can do that with the code in my answer (if you add `data_type` to the list of columns that you select). Your new code is even more confusing then the old one - especially because it's invalid PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

Oracle uses a period for decimals. The comma is throwing it out. Try:

```
  DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
OLD_LENGTH varchar2(50);
BEGIN
COL_COUNT:= 0;
SELECT DATA_LENGTH||'.'||DATA_PRECISION INTO OLD_LENGTH  FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME='EX_EMPLOYEE' AND COLUMN_NAME='ID';
SELECT COUNT (1) INTO COL_COUNT FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='EX_EMPLOYEE'AND COLUMN_NAME='ID';
IF (COL_COUNT <> 0 AND to_number(OLD_LENGTH) < 6.2 ) THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TABLE EX_EMPLOYEE MODIFY ID NUMERIC(6,2)');
END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "." separator instead of the comma:
`select to_number('6.2') from dual; --works
select to_number('6,2') from dual; --returns error`