# Comparing 2 numbers with different precision and scale

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a condition to check 2 columns both data type number.

for example varchar2(100) is larger then varchar2(50) because it holds more character. Now for numbers, number(9,1) is larger then number(10,3) because it hold more number ?

In the below example `F_ID`is a `number(10,3)` , I want to compare with another column which is `number(9,3)`

```
DECLARE COL_COUNT NUMBER;
OLD_PREC NUMBER(5);
OLD_SCALE NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
SELECT DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE INTO OLD_PREC,OLD_SCALE FROM USER_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='EX_EMPLOYEE' AND COLUMN_NAME='F_ID';
IF ( OLD_PREC <= 9 AND OLD_SCALE < 3 ) THEN
-- do something
```

Can I compare it like this? Because `(9,1) = 12345678,1`  and `(10,3) = 123456,1234`, so basically 9,1 is larger then 10,3 right?

Comment: I read this a couple times, but I just can't make out what you're trying to do. Can you reformulate your requirement?

Comment: @wvdz varchar2(100) is larger then varchar2(50) right ? it holds more character . okay now for numbers, number(9,1) is larger then number(10,3) because it hold more number ?.. anyway ill improve my question

Comment: @XING is it clear now ?

Comment: if you compare two varchars, then the comparison is lexicographical. so 'a' is smaller than n 'bbbb', and 'aaaa' is also smaller than 'b'. What does this have to do with the length of the field?

Comment: For me it is still not clear. What are you going to compare? How much memory is used to store numbers?

Comment: As far i could understand you want to compare the datatypes declaration. So in that case you can decalre a variable and get the legth of the variable and compare it.

Comment: I can't understand it either. Why do you check the dictionary ? Are you storing numbers in VARCHAR columns ? A number(9,1) column can be lower, equal or greater than a column number(10,3), it depends on the contents of the table !

Comment: How is this different then your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972827/oracle-expression-of-wrong-type-while-checking-variable

Comment: I agree with everyone else - you need to explain better. Tell us WHY you are looking at comparisons this way. WHY do you need to check the precision and scale of numbers? I can see one possible reason, but please tell us what yours is. You described to us the solution to a problem (the solution you are trying to build), but what is the original problem where this all started? My example is: you have several numbers stored in a column `col` of a table `tbl`. You want to know if the number `pi` is among them (rounded appropriately). You could test for `c = 3.14`, but this depends on scale.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had an error with that question , here I am trying to understand the logice of comapring 2 numbers

Comment: If column `c` is declared NUMBER(9,1) then none of the numbers in column `c` will ever equal a number with two significant decimals. If instead it's NUMBER(9,4), `c` may be 3.1416 and this is not equal to 3.14 either. So to write the proper comparison, you need to know the scale (and perhaps precision) of `c`. Is that the kind of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying this to normalize scale and precision of two different columns with number data type, and making them consistent through your script?

Comment: @mathguy ill tell you my scenario, I want to modify a column of data type number in condition that the length and the precision is higher then then old value. for example on the database it's `number(10,3)` my alter statement is  `number (9,1)` so logicaly its larger then on the database, so how to do this condition ? did you understand my need ?

Comment: @KrishnatMolawade I am just comparing them , please check my above comment

Comment: @Moudiz - I understand your words (your English), but not the logic. You want to alter a column in a table. Currently the column is NUMBER(10,3) and you want to alter it to NUMBER(9,1). OK, but WHY do you want to do that? NUMBER(10,3) will hold numbers with up to seven digits before the decimal point, plus three decimal places. (9,1) will accept up to 8 digits before decimal point, but only one decimal place. I would understand going from (10,3) to (11,3) if you need to hold larger numbers, but why to (9,1)? You will lose information in that process.

Comment: Also, I didn't test, but I believe Oracle may allow you to "alter" the column from (10,3) to (11,3) with minimal work. Since (9,1) loses information compared to (10,3), it may not let you; you may have to create a new column, populate it (by rounding the old numbers to one decimal place), delete the old column, and rename the new column to the old column name. And you will have to recreate constraints, indexes, etc. on the new column. And it will be a big pain if the old column was part of a composite constraint etc.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores numbers in scientific notation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1833 so there is no direct relation between decimal precision and space it needs to store the number.

In case you want to check which one will take more space as a text why don't compare `length(to_char(n1)) > length(to_char(n2))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
column_name NUMBER (precision, scale)
```

In the declaration above the precision is total number of digits and scale is number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

By subtracting the scale from precision you'll find the digits left of the decimal point.

Hence,
`NUMBER (9,1) could contain maximum 8 length number left of the decimal point : 9999,9999.9`
and 
`NUMBER (10,3) could contain maximum 7 length number left of the decimal point : 999,9999.999`

Considering this you can say that first column is larger.

Just be aware that in case when the the digits right of the decimal point are `equal` you have to check the `scale`

`NUMBER (8,1) could contain maximum 7 length number left of the decimal point: 999,9999.9`
and 
`NUMBER (10,3) could contain maximum 7 length number left of the decimal point : 999,9999.999`
But in this case the second column is larger because it has 3 length `scale`

Comment: you understand my problem, how then I compare them ? How I compare 2 number with precision ?

Comment: Please specify, do you have to identify which column is larger ? or you have to identify which column VALUE is greater than another column VALUE ?

Comment: I want to identfiy which value is larger .

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> "varchar2(100) is larger then varchar2(50) right ? it holds more
>   character . okay now for numbers, number(9,1) is larger then
>   number(10,3) "

As an infrence i can only get that you wanted to compare the data types. See below how you can do it. I uses a PLSQL anonymous block to explain.

```
declare
   a   number (9, 1);
   b   number (10, 3);
begin
   if length (a) > length (b)
   then
      dbms_output.put_line ('a is bigger');
   else
      dbms_output.put_line ('a is smaller');
   end if;
end;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
a is smaller

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```